# How to Create Batch code to set each line of output into separate variables

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, set, wmic

I use this code to set first output line into variable but can't set second or other line into another variables.

```bash
wmic memorychip get capacity
```

Output:

```
Capacity
4294967296
4294967296
8589934592
4294967296
```

**My code:**

```bash
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic memorychip get capacity /value ^| find /i "Name="') do set capacity=%%A

echo %capacity%
```

Output:

```
4294967296
```

But I need some code like:

```bash
do set capacity1=%%A & capacity2=%%B & capacity3=%%C & capacity4=%%D

echo %capacity1%
echo %capacity2%
echo %capacity3%
echo %capacity4%
```

I need to set each line into separate variables.

---

I need separate variables like `%capacity1%` and `%capacity2%` etc. I'll use each value to calculate using more code.

Comment: [arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to generate a collection of variables (usually called an array, but batch *technically* doesn't have arrays (it's complicated)), you'll have to set up a variable to keep track of a counter and increment that every time a new line is read.

In order to update and use a variable inside of the same `for` loop, you'll need to enable delayed expansion (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected) for more information about that).

Also, because `wmic` outputs in UTF-16 and each line ends in \r\r\n instead of \r\n, you'll need to run each line through a second `for` loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "capacity_counter=0"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic memorychip get capacity /value ^| find /I "Capacity="') do (
    for /f %%B in ("%%~A") do (
        set /a capacity_counter+=1
        set "capacity[!capacity_counter!]=%%B"
    )
)

for /L %%A in (1,1,!capacity_counter!) do echo Capacity %%A: !capacity[%%A]!
```

Comment: thank you for answer but need separate variables like %capacity1% and %capacity2% and ... to use each value to calculate into another code. don't just ECHO them

Comment: @SinaSadeh, the variables from this code are named `capacity[1], capacity[2], etc....`.  What don't you understand about the code?

Answer (score 2):

Note: there might be other memory besides "Main Memory" (`System ROM` on one of my systems for example, and potentially other memory types, depending on the system).

`Wmic` can filter for `MemoryType`, but apparently, this is not reliable for DDR4 (and probably above), but there is also `SMBIOSMemoryType`, which returns `18` for DDR, `21` for DDR2, etc., so I took an approach to check if it's "18 or above". (which means, it won't work for pre-DDR memory, but maybe it can be adapted to include them (for example above mentioned SystemROM returns a `9`))

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set i=0
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in ('"wmic memorychip get capacity,smbiosmemorytype"') do (
  if %%b geq 18 (
    for /f "delims=" %%c in ("%%a") do (
      set /a i+=1
      set  "_mem[!i!]=%%c"
    )
  )
)
set _mem[
for /l %%i in (1,1,%i%) do echo Dimm %%i is !_mem[%%i]!.
```

---

*Here's a reference table for the Memory Device Types* (Thank you, Copmpo)

```
SMBIOSMemoryType,Value
1,Other
2,Unknown
3,DRAM
4,EDRAM
5,VRAM
6,SRAM
7,RAM
8,ROM
9,FLASH
10,EEPROM
11,FEPROM
12,EPROM
13,CDRAM
14,3DRAM
15,SDRAM
16,SGRAM
17,RDRAM
18,DDR
19,DDR2
20,DDR2 FB-DIMM
21,Reserved
22,Reserved
23,Reserved
24,DDR3
25,FBD2
26,DDR4
27,LPDDR
28,LPDDR2
29,LPDDR3
30,LPDDR4
31,Logical non-volatile device
32,HBM (High Bandwidth Memory)
33,HBM2 (High Bandwidth Memory Generation 2)
34,DDR5
35,LPDDR5
36,HBM3 (High Bandwidth Memory Generation 3)
```

**Edit** Based on the table provided by Compo, I lowered the `20` to `18` to include DDR (first version of DDRx). Any hardware below that (as Main Memory) is probably not able to run a modern Windows (`wmic.exe`) or is *very* specialized.

Note: for Consumer/Home PCs SomethingDark's answer is probably sufficient - I've got an HP Z-series workstation which lists an additional entry, so I took care of that.

Comment: Thanks; I've corrected the line ending in my code. I've got DDR4 RAM, so `memorytype` is 0 for me instead of 24.

Comment: @SomethingDark: uh - you opened a real rabbithole here. I found no reliable method to filter for mainmemory (memorytype, formfactor differ depending on hardware, `DataWidth` seems to work best so far, but I've got only 64 bit computers to check, it might be different on older systems. `SerialNumber` (existence) does work for MY systems, but I doubt, it's reliable). [related PowerShell solution](https://superuser.com/a/1540441/217811)

Comment: @Stephen - According to [Microsoft's Win32_PhysicalMemory WMI class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory), SMBIOSMemoryType being 20 or higher should indicate DDRx RAM.

Comment: @SomethingDark: already found and adapted my answer.

Comment: thank you for answer but need separate variables like %capacity1% and %capacity2% and ... to use each value to calculate into another code. don't just ECHO them

Comment: @SinaSadeh you were given separate variables. They are named `_mem[1], _mem[2], etc.....`. Saying **"don't just ECHO them"** is a bit ignorant.  By using SET and as well as a using the echo command to display them proves the variables exist.

Comment: FYI `SMBIOSMemoryType` is displaying `35` on the DDR5 unit I've just checked.

Comment: @Compo Thank you. Didn't find a complete reference. So far we have verified 24=DDR3, 26=DDR4 and 35=DDR5 (which works fine so far, as they are all geq 20)

Comment: Courtesy Edit made with reference values.

Comment: I think  28 OR 34 = DDR5

Answer (score 2):

Just one more way to do this. There is another option to create the array of variables. Instead of doing it inside the initial FOR commands, you can just assign all the capacity values to a single variable first. Then you can use some neat trickery with how variable expansion and command execution works in batch files. This was documented first on DosTips.com in 2015 by Aacini (Antonio).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Initialize capacity variable and assing all values to a single variable
set "capacity="
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic memorychip get capacity /value ^| find /I "Capacity="') do (
    for /f %%B in ("%%~A") do if not defined capacity (set "capacity=%%B") else (set "capacity=!capacity! %%B")
)
REM Initialize array counter
set "i=1"
REM create array variables
set "capacity!i!=%capacity: =" & set /A i+=1 & set "capacity!i!=%"
REM Display all Capacity variables that are defined
set capacity
```